# Mutual SSL - getting the key/truststores in the proper formats

Tags: java, soap, jaxb, ssl, pki

I generated a CSR using OpenSSL:

```
openssl req -out MyCompanyCsr.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout MyCompanyPrivateKey.key
```

So starting out, we have:

```
- MyCompanyPrivateKey.key
- MyCompanyCsr.csr
```

Then I sent it to our integration partner, who responded with 3 files:

```
- PartnerIntermediateCa.crt
- PartnerRootCa.crt
- MyCompanyCsr.crt
```

Now I need to connect to their web service using mutual SSL.  To do this, I know I need to set the truststore and keystore in my SSLSocketFactory for JAXB.

I'm instantiating the keystore and truststore in Java using:

```
      KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
      InputStream tsis = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(trustStorePath);
      trustStore.load(tsis, "mypassword".toCharArray());
      tsis.close();

      KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
      InputStream ksis = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(keyStorePath);
      keyStore.load(ksis, "mypassword".toCharArray());
      if (ksis != null) {
        ksis.close();
      }

      TrustManagerFactory tmf =
          TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      tmf.init(trustStore);

      KeyManagerFactory kmf =
          KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      kmf.init(keyStore, "mypassword".toCharArray());
```

However, attempting to use this code in connecting to the server throws a `SSLHandshakeException` with the message `http.client.failed`:

```
com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

The `keystore` and `truststore` I'm using were exported from my browser, with the Client private key as a `PKCS` and the Server cert as a `x509 Cert PKCS#7 w/ Chain'.  Then opened them up in Portecle and exported them both as`JKS` files.

Assuming the Java code is legit, how can I be sure I have correctly created the `keystore` and `truststore`?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out.  I used FireFox and [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/).

Install the Server Certs and Private Key in the browser.

**Note:** One always confusing point: both the "truststore" and "keystore" are *keystores* as far as Portecle / Java goes.  The only difference is the one we use as *our keystore* in the client is going to have our private keys in addition to the public certs.

**TrustStore built with the server certificates:**

- Go to a URL at the address, click next to the address bar (lock icon, showing SSL enabled)
- Security tab > View Certificate > Details tab > Export button
- Choose type: X.509 Certificate with chain (PKCS#7).
- Save somewhere as ffTestServerCert.crt
- Open in Portecle via: Examine menu > Examine Certificate > select ffTestServerCert.crt
- You can now see the certs contained in this (I see 3 for instance).  Each needs to be exported by itself.  Click arrow buttons at top of page and for each:
- Click "PEM Encoding" button
- Save button
- Save as .pem file on disk (for this example, say I have caCert1.pem, caCert2.pem, caCert3.pem)
- Create new Keystore in Portecle: File > New Keystore > JKS
- For each exported cert from above (caCert1.pem, caCert2.pem, caCert3.pem), do:
- Tools > Import Trusted Certificate > select the .pem > Import button
- Message box pops up saying we need to determine if we trust this certificate.
- Click Ok > Ok (if you trust the cert) > Yes > Enter alias (I left it at default) > Ok
- Repeat for any other certs you want to import (I did all 3).
- Save keystore in Portecle:
- File > Save Keystore as... >
- Enter **truststore** password twice
- Enter name to save it as, such as **clientTrustStore.jks**

Congrats, that's the valid **truststore**.

**KeyStore built with the private key and server certificates:**

- First import the private keys into FireFox (or Chrome or IE)
- Use the browser to export the private key in PKCS format.
- Firefox > Preferences > Advanced tab > Encryption tab > View Certificates > Your Certificates
- Select the one you want to export > click Backup button
- (Only option here is PKCS12 format, which is what we want)
- Choose a name - clientKeys.p12
- enter a password for the **keystore**
- Should say they were exported, click Ok
- Open keys in Portecle
- File > Open Keystore > choose clientKeys.p12 we saved above
- Enter password chosen above
- Convert to JKS using Portecle
- Tools > Change Keystore Type > JKS
- Read the warning message about how the current type doesn't support key-pair entry passwords
- **Important:** this action sets the *inside* password for the key-pair entries `password`.
- To change the password of the internal key-pair entries, select any 'key pair' in the file in Portecle (their icon will be a pair of keys, on on top of the other)
- Right click 'key pair entry' > Set Password
- Enter old password (which is 'password') and enter new passwords to what you want
- Hit Ok
- Save **keystore**:
- In Portecle do: File > Save Keystore As > enter name, such as **clientKeyStore.jks**
- Hit Save

**Finished**

Now you have the correctly-configured **clientTrustStore.jks** and **clientKeyStore.jks** for authenticating your client.

To see an example of how these can now be used, you can check out:
[SOAP with mutual SSL - how to send over credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11908248/101095)